# PDFBox "Symbolic fonts must have a built-in encoding" error when using PDFTextStripper.getText()

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using Apache PDFBox 2.0.2.
Loading pdf documents from web to get a text inside.

```
URL u = new URL("url/to/file.pdf");
PDDocument pddDocument = PDDocument.load(u.openStream());

PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String doc = textStripper.getText(pddDocument);
```

The problem is, sometimes I got IllegalArgumentException: "Symbolic fonts must have a built-in encoding" and can't extract text from the PDF.

Please help.

Comment: Please link to the PDF file.

Comment: Thx! For ex, I can't convert to text from http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Park_Efficient_and_Robust_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf . I'm trying to extract text from all of the pdfs on http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/CVPR2016.py . However, 27 out of 640 files are not able to read with same exception.

Comment: I have opened an issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3403

Comment: @Tilman Thank you so much. I didn't think it could be a bug...

Comment: you can get a -SNAPSHOT build now: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.3-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, that's awesome! Using that, I could extract from all of the 27 pdf files failed previously. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already indicated by @Tilman opening a bug issue in the PDFBox Jira, this behavior is a bug:

The `DictionaryEncoding` constructor retrieves an `Encoding` instance for the base encoding of a font using `Encoding.getInstance` and is well aware that this method may return `null`:

```
base = Encoding.getInstance(name); // may be null
```

If it is `null`, though, and PDFBox has not been able to determine a built-in encoding of the font, the observed exception is thrown:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Symbolic fonts must have a built-in " + 
                                   "encoding");
```

In the case at hand, the base encoding is **MacExpertEncoding** which is one of the possible base encodings explicitly named by the PDF specification. Unfortunately `Encoding.getInstance` does not know this encoding and, therefore, returns `null` which in turn triggers the exception as PDFBox also could not identify a built-in encoding.

---

Thus, a fix should include the addition of an `Encoding` class for **MacExpertEncoding** and extending `Encoding.getInstance` accordingly.

Furthermore, one should consider not throwing the exception at all: There are numerous situation where there is no need for an implicit or explicit base encoding, e.g. if the **Differences** explicitly provide a mapping for each character code or (in case of pure text extraction) if the font has a good **ToUnicode** table.

Comment: Thank you for very detailed answer. Now I understand what's going on.
BTW Is there any way to give a default encoding before I extract texts from TextStripper so that it can go through without signaling exception?

Comment: @Hub no. Its a bug and it will be fixed tonight.